# insert data to external table from an external table

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, external-tables

While inserting data to an external table-2 from an external table-1 the data of external table-2 gets stored in `/user/hive/warehouse/db-name/table-name/`,but as an external table it should not store data into warehouse directory right?
Should we specify location for storing data to external table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you will have to mention the location while creating the external table.
You can simply do it in following way.

Create the tables table1 and table2:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table1(col1 INT, col2 BIGINT,col3 STRING)
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 STORED AS TEXTFILE
 LOCATION '<hdfs_location1>';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table2(col21 INT, col22 BIGINT,col23 STRING)
     ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
     STORED AS TEXTFILE
     LOCATION '<hdfs_location2>';
```

Now insert the data from table1 to table 2

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table2(col21,col22,col23) SELECT * FROM table1
```

It will copy the data from table 1 to table2 hdfs location.

Please note that [CTAS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS))(Create table AS Select) is not supported for external tables.

Answer (score 1):

Any table you create in hive whether its internal or external file is moved to '/user/hive/warehouse' or whatever you specify in 
   `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` 
in hive-site.xml

External table is created- to prevent the data loss when someone drop the table accidentally. Try to create 2 external tables and browse the filesystem. You can easily understand the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have created external table-2 without specifying LOCATION. Try using below syntax

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [db_name.]table_name
  [(col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)]
  [PARTITIONED BY (col_name data_type [COMMENT col_comment], ...)]
  [CLUSTERED BY (col_name, col_name, ...) [SORTED BY (col_name [ASC|DESC], ...)] INTO num_buckets BUCKETS]
  [
   [ROW FORMAT row_format] 
   [STORED AS file_format]
     | STORED BY 'storage.handler.class.name' [WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (...)]
  ]
  [LOCATION hdfs_path]
  [TBLPROPERTIES (property_name=property_value, ...)]
  [AS select_statement];
```

Comment: [CTAS](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableAsSelect(CTAS))(Create table as select) is not supported for External tables.